# Path Issue Causing System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nunit

I added a solution to my project, just for unit tests (NUnit)
I have included references to all of the dlls the test solution needs

but..

I am getting the following file not found error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '\bin\Debug\bin\aLibrary.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The issue is that on build, all of my dlls are correctly getting placed into
`MySolution/bin/Debug` , which is what I have the path set to in the project properties, but the error is telling me that the application is looking in `MySolution/bin/Debug/bin`

The solution settings show the correct path
[image]

If I copy those dll files from `MySolution/bin/Debug` to `MySolution/bin/Debug/bin` all works as expected.

**Question**
I have no idea where the path is being set. How do I correct or where should I look? Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: your output path in the screenshot is pointing at `bin\Debug`

Comment: I know. So I guess that's why I am confused. Not sure where bin/Debug/bin is coming from

Comment: ah right, the way you described the question I thought you actually *want* the build path to be `MySolution/bin/Debug/bin`. Is the problem DLL a third party DLL or a project in your solution?

Comment: It's a 3rd party dll

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, go to properties, reference paths and check if you need to change the path: more described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: reference path is not set so nothing to change. None of my projects have reference path set and they all work fine except for this one. Thanks, anyhow

Comment: Then I would track down that particular reference in the project references and see its path/properties. You can always remove that problematic reference and add it from the correct path in your project, I hope that helps